# Doctrine ManytoOne ArrayCollection only populated with one value

Tags: doctrine, silex

I have an ArrayCollection relationship defined in two entities as such:

```php
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints= {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email_UNIQUE", columns={"email"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="email_id", columns={"id_user", "email"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entities\Usercharts", inversedBy="charts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")
 */
private $userscharts;
```

and

```php
/**
 * Useritems
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="useritems", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="userid", columns={"id_user"}), @ORM\Index(name="chartno", columns={"chart_no"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Usercharts
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\User", mappedBy="userscharts")
 *
 */
private $charts;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->charts = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

the data structure of usercharts:
[image]

The problem is the ArrayCollection is only being populated with one value in what appears to be the last item in the populated table; for example for this data,

```
'1201','4769'
'1202','4769'
'1400','4769'
'1434','4769'
'1435','4769'
'1510','4769'
'2000','4769'
'2050','4769'
'3726','4769'
'3808','4769'
'7950','4769'
```

The ArrayCollection $charts value returns only 7950  in the template twig

```twig
    <ul>
        {% for chart in user.userscharts %}
            <li>{{ chart.chartno }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I tried adding the primary key identifier also for the chart_no (which seems to make sense to do) :

```php
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="chart_no", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $chartno = '';
```

but this results in an

```
OutOfBoundsException.php line 40
at OutOfBoundsException::missingPrimaryKeyValue('App\Entities\Usercharts', 'chartno') in AbstractProxyFactory.php line 125
at AbstractProxyFactory->getProxy('App\Entities\Usercharts', array('userid' => '4769')) in UnitOfWork.php line 2698
```

How to properly modify the entity doctrine declarations to acquire the full array of charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your associations types are incorrect. One user can have many charts, so association should be `OneToMany` for `$userscharts` and `ManyToOne` for `$charts`

```
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\Usercharts", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $userscharts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userscharts = new ArrayCollection();
}
.....

class Usercharts
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entities\User", inversedBy="userscharts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")
 */
private $user;
```